# ZooKeeper latest value is not reloaded without restarting server

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, spring-bean

I am using ZooKeeper with spring boot. And In application.properties file I am using below properties as shown below.

```
minio.url=${minio.connection-string}
minio.access.key=${minio.accesskey}
```

where minio.connection-string and minio.accesskey value will be came from ZooKeeper znode data. I am using minio.url and minio.access.key in other Spring boot bean as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class MinioClientConf
{

    @Value("${minio.url}")
    private String minioUrl;

    @Value("${minio.access.key}")
    private String minioKey;
.
.
```

When I start my spring boot application then all stuff works but when I change ZooKeeper node value then it is not reflecting in bean value without re-starting server.
My problem is that I want to reload latest zookeeper value without re-starting server. I have also tried with refresh scope annotation but it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure that your Minio url values updated configuration server first. Please check below url how to configure server first https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html . Then it will reflect your configuration clients

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that use @ConfigurationProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties("minio")
public class MinioClientConf
    {
       private String minioUrl;
       private String minioKey;
    .
    .
```

For more details [click here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Comment: So the problem is you are not getting value for minio from ZooKeeper. Have you checked?

Comment: Actually, through cli, I can get updated value of ZooKeeper node. But JavaBean property has still old value.